# Create from-to matrix in R from row of origins and row of destinations

Tags: r, dplyr

My data is in this format:

```
From        To        Count
Paris       London    10
Paris       HongKong  8 
London      HongKong  3 
London      Paris     2
NewYork     Paris     5
NewYork     HongKong  4
NewYork     London    6
HongKong    Paris     12
HongKong    London    10 
HongKong    NewYork   11
```

I want to construct a matrix with From on the rows, To on the columns, and the number of occurrences in the cells. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- read.table(text = "From        To
Paris       London
                 Paris       HongKong
                 Paris       HongKong
                 Paris       HongKong
                 London      HongKong
                 London      HongKong
                 London      Paris
                 NewYork     Paris
                 NewYork     Paris
                 NewYork     HongKong
                 NewYork     HongKong
                 NewYork     HongKong
                 NewYork     HongKong
                 NewYork     London
                 NewYork     London
                 HongKong    Paris
                 HongKong    London
                 HongKong    Paris
                 HongKong    Paris
                 HongKong    NewYork
                 HongKong    NewYork", header = TRUE)
```

We can simply get a crosstable and use `as.matrix()` to reclass it to matrix.

```
as.matrix(table(df$From, df$To))

           HongKong London NewYork Paris
  HongKong        0      1       2     3
  London          2      0       0     1
  NewYork         4      2       0     2
  Paris           3      1       0     0
```